# IE10 issue with calculating widths

Tags: javascript, prototype, internet-explorer-10

I'm having trouble with a tableview in IE10. For some reason IE10 tries to measure the widths of the cells before they are drawn on the screen, whilst other browser do not. The difference can clearly be seen when placing a breakpoint in IE10 vs another version/browser.

The code is pretty complex but I've managed to create a snippet which reproduces the issue:

```
var cells = 40;
var rows = 1000;

console.clear();

function measure(obj) {
    obj = $(obj);
    console.log(obj.getWidth());
}

var randomNumber = function (scale, offset) {
    scale = scale || 10;
    offset = offset || 50;
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) * scale) + offset;
};

var output = "<table><thead><tr>";

for (var i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
    output += "<th width='" + randomNumber() + "'></th>";
}
output += "</tr></thead><tbody>";
for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    output += "<tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
        output += "<td></td>";
    }
    output += "</tr>";
}

output += "</tbody></table>";

// Insert into DOM.
$(document).body.insert(output);

// Measure the elements.    
$$('th').each(measure);
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwp5A/1/)

Now depending on the amount of columns and rows IE10 will return the correct widths or when more complex, it will return 0 for all (you can tweak the numbers to test this).

I've tried delaying the getWidth function with a loop while returning 0 but all that does is lock up the browser and returns 0 eventually as well. 
Any ideas how I can make IE10 return the correct width?

Answer (score 0):

This clearly looks like a defect in IE10. I was able to get your measurements to show up by doing this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $$('th').each(measure);
}, 1000);
```

It looks as if IE10 is doing some sort of delayed rendering of the elements and the measure function is executing before the new elements are laid out.

Clearly not an ideal solution, but it may give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks. We solved the issue by appending a script tag to the HTML output.